# Longest subsequence of S that is balanced

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Given question:**
A string of parentheses is said to be
balanced if the left- and right-parentheses in the string can be paired off properly. For example, the strings "(())" and "()()" are both balanced, while the string "(()(" is not
balanced. 
Given a string **S** of length **n** consisting of parentheses, suppose you want to find the longest subsequence of **S** that is balanced. Using dynamic programming, design an algorithm that finds the longest balanced subsequence of **S** in **O(n^3)** time.

My approach:
Suppose given string: S[1 2 ... n]
A valid sub-sequence can end at S[i] iff S[i] == ')' i.e. S[i] is a closing brace and there exists at least one unused opening brace previous to S[i]. which could be implemented in O(N).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int n = s.length(), o_count = 0, len = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        if(s[i] == '('){
            ++o_count;
            continue;
        }
        else if(s[i] == ')' && o_count > 0){
            ++len;
            --o_count;
        }
    }
    cout << len << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried a couple of test cases and they seem to be working fine. Am I missing something here? If not, then how can I also design an **O(n^3)** Dynamic Programming solution for this problem?
This is the definition of [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) that I'm using.

Thanks!

Comment: Your program returns 2 for `()()` and 3 for `()()(()`. Both should be 4.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - why shouldn't the second one be `6`? If his program returns the number of pairs, it returns the correct result for those 2. Multiply by 2 for the actual string length.

Comment: @IVlad The balanced parentheses have to be adjacent.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - I'm not sure what you mean. `()()()` is a balanced subsequence of length 6 (3*2) of `()()(()`. It's also the longest balanced subsequence, and the OP's program correctly finds (half of) its length.

Comment: Yes, return value is the no. of pairs in the longest sub-sequence which is properly balanced.

Comment: Ah, right you are! Items in a subsequence don't need to be adjacent. I assume(d) the problem is to find the longest balanced sub-**string** since the longest sub-sequence is a trivial problem.

Comment: @srbhkmr Why did you settle for `O(n^3)` solution when the above problem can be solved in `O(n lg n)`. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643697/longest-subsequence-of-balanced-parentheses or for that matter this question http://codeforces.com/contest/380/problem/C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `O(n^3)` DP this should work I think:

```
dp[i, j] = longest balanced subsequence in [i .. j]
dp[i, i] = 0
dp[i, i + 1] = 2 if [i, i + 1] == "()", 0 otherwise

dp[i, j] = max{dp[i, k] + dp[k + 1, j] : j > i + 1} in general
```

This can be implemented similar to how [optimal matrix chain multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) is.

Your algorithm also seems correct to me, see for example this problem:

http://xorswap.com/questions/107-implement-a-function-to-balance-parentheses-in-a-string-using-the-minimum-nu

Where the solutions are basically the same as yours.

You are only ignoring the extra brackets, so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I too think that DP should work. Thanks for that link I thought I was missing something with that approach.

Comment: This answer is not correct. consider (()), the algorithm above returns 0 while it must be 4.

Comment: @Nima - that's correct! You can't apply the same algorithm. In that case, the OP's algorithm should do well. Unfortunately I cannot delete this answer anymore.

Comment: You can find the answer for the generalized version of this question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583771/grouping-symbols-maximum-length-balanced-subsequent/27584399?noredirect=1#comment43595173_27584399

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `O(n^2)` time and space DP solution in Java:

```
public int findLongestBalancedSubsequence(String seq, int n) {
    int[][] lengths = new int[n][n];

    for (int l = 1; l < n; l++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - l; i++) {
            int j = i + l;
            // Ends are balanced.
            if (seq.charAt(i) == '(' && seq.charAt(j) == ')') {
                // lengths[i, j] = max(lengths[i + 1, j - 1] + 2, lengths[i + 1, j] + 
                // lengths[i, j - 1] - lengths[i + 1, j - 1])
                if (lengths[i + 1][j - 1] + 2 > lengths[i + 1][j] +
                    lengths[i][j - 1] - lengths[i + 1][j - 1])
                    lengths[i][j] = lengths[i + 1][j - 1] + 2;
                else
                    lengths[i][j] = lengths[i + 1][j] +
                        lengths[i][j - 1] - lengths[i + 1][j - 1];
            // Ends are not balanced.
            } else {
                // lengths[i, j] = max(lengths[i + 1, j], lengths[i, j - 1])
                if (lengths[i + 1][j] > lengths[i][j - 1])
                    lengths[i][j] = lengths[i + 1][j];
                else
                    lengths[i][j] = lengths[i][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return lengths[0][n - 1];
}
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation on `lengths[i, j] = max(lengths[i + 1, j - 1] + 2, lengths[i + 1, j] + lengths[i, j - 1] - lengths[i + 1, j - 1])`. Thanks.