# Grouping Symbols Maximum Length Balanced Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

Consider B to be a sequence of grouping symbols (, ), [, ], {, and }. B is called a Balanced sequence if it is of length 0 or B is of one of the following forms: { X } Y or [ X ] Y or { X } Y where X and Y are Balanced themselves. Example for Balanced : ( ) - { [ ] ( ) } [ ] - ...

Now the question is to find an efficient algorithm to find maximum length balanced subsequence (not necessarily contiguous) of a given input which is an string of these grouping symbols.

For example if input is **( ) { ( [ ) ] { ( ] ) } } [ ]** , one of the max-length subsequences is **( ) { [ ] { ( ) } } [ ]**

I am almost sure the solution is DP but anyway I solve it I find examples in which my algorithm doesn't work. there is only one approach I am sure about, which is a combination of DP and Divide and Conquer. But it is not efficient because anyway D&C part is going to solve some overlapping problems over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make a couple of simple observation:

1. Any balanced subsequence can be represented as `A1 X A2 Y`, where `A1` and `A2` are two matched brackets((), [] or {}), `X` and `Y` are balanced subsequences(they can be empty). It is true because there is a leftmost bracket in any balanced non-empty subsequence and it must be matched to something.
2. `X` and `Y` are independent. If it is not the case, the subsequence is not balanced.

These observations give us a dynamic programming solution:

Let's assume `f(L, R)` is the longest balanced subsequence for `[L, R]` subarray.
The base is an empty subarray. Transition are as follows:

```
f(L, R) = max(   
     f(L + 1, R) // ignore the first element    
     max(f(L + 1, K - 1) + 2 + f(K + 1, R)) for all K if brackets at positions L and K match
)
```

The time complexity is `O(N^3)` because there are `O(N^2)` subarrays and there are `O(N)` transitions for each of them. It is possible to reconstruct the longest subsequence itself using standard answer reconstruction techniques.

Comment: So as I get it range for k must be  L+2 <= k <= R. But, what if L matches L+1 and it is part of answer?

Comment: @Nima I assume that we can use an empty range with L > R(the answer is zero for it). It allows us to avoid handling this case specially.

Comment: The Knuth-Yao quadrangle inequality speedup applies to this problem, right? So you can do it in O(n^2)?

Comment: @harold No, it does not apply to this problem. For example, it is not true for a string ({)} and a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 and d = 3.